# React-Native-Maps stop infinite scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

When using React-Native-Maps is it possible to stop the maps 'wrapping' and creating an infinite scroll? IE When you hit the end of the world, the map stops?

Answer (score 1):

To check that user has dragged the map out of the bound what you can do is check the current lat and lng. If the current lat and lng is out of the bound then bring the user back to last valid lat and lng. See the below code:-

```
let lastValidCenter
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     region: {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }
  }
 lastValidCenter = this.state.region
}

onRegionChange = (region) => {
  if(this.state.region.contains(region)) {
    lastValidCenter = region;
    return;
  }
  this.setState({
     region: lastValidCenter
  })
}

<MapView
  region={this.state.region}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
</MapView>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. I'm not sure how this stops the map wrapping but I'll give it a go.

Comment: This doesn't work, it just stops the user scrolling? It should only stop the map wrapping around